# Get File Names from Windows Share in Web App

Tags: java

I need to get a list of file names from a network Windows Share folder.

The following works great when I am running it in my local host environment but gives this error when I try to run it in my web application server hosted on an iSeries(as400 box) - still on same network:

HistoricalFileList: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

```
public class HistoricalFileList {

private List<HistoricalFilePath> historicalfilelist = null;

public HistoricalFileList(DrawingNumberV7 dnV7, DefaultPrams dft, QMSConfigurationData qmsconfigData){

    try{

        String drawingsServerShare = "";//"\\gvsvr03\"

        for(QMSConfiguration q: qmsconfigData.getConfigparamlist()){

            if(q.getProperty().equals("drawingsServerShare")){
                drawingsServerShare = q.getValue();
                break;
            }

        }

        String dmdrawno = "";
        String directoryName = null;
        String serverDir = "Drawings\\Historical PDF";
        List wildcardlist = new LinkedList();
        List temp = new LinkedList();

        dmdrawno = dnV7.getDrawingnumber();
        directoryName = drawingsServerShare + serverDir + "\\" + dnV7.getDrawingnumbersubdirectory() + "\\";

        if(dft.getQms_mode().equals("TEST")){

            System.out.println("HistoricalFileList: directoryName: " + directoryName);

        }

        File directory = new File(directoryName);

        wildcardlist.add(dmdrawno + "*.PDF");
        wildcardlist.add(dmdrawno + "*.pdf");

        List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(directory, new WildcardFileFilter(wildcardlist), null);
        for (File file : files) {
            temp.add(new HistoricalFilePath(dnV7, file.getName()));
        }

        historicalfilelist = temp;

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("HistoricalFileList: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public List<HistoricalFilePath> getHistoricalfilelist() {
    return historicalfilelist;
}


}
```

Update to add stacktrace:

```
[1/8/18 14:44:33:339 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles(FileUtils.java:292)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.FAIWebApp.DrawingNumber.HistoricalFileList.<init>(HistoricalFileList.java:71)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.FAIWebApp.DrawingNumber.DrawingNumberFilePathList.<init>(DrawingNumberFilePathList.java:26)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.FAIWebApp.DrawingNumber.DrawingNumberV7.<init>(DrawingNumberV7.java:84)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.FAIWebApp.DrawingNumber.DrawingNumberDataV7.<init>(DrawingNumberDataV7.java:50)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.FAIWebApp.DrawingNumber.DrawingNumberControllerServlet.doPost(DrawingNumberControllerServlet.java:83)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.FAIWebApp.QMSFilter.doFilter(QMSFilter.java:96)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:340 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:947)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:558)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:608)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:985)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1074)
[1/8/18 14:44:33:341 CST] 000000a4 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Update #2

Shows the isDirectory result:

```
[1/8/18 22:27:31:381 CST] 000000a7 SystemOut     O HistoricalFileList: directoryName: \\gvsvr03\Drawings\Historical PDF\882000\
[1/8/18 22:27:31:381 CST] 000000a7 SystemOut     O HistoricalFileList: directoryName: false
[1/8/18 22:27:31:381 CST] 000000a7 SystemOut     O HistoricalFileList: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
```

Update to show solution:

```
public class HistoricalFileList {

private List<HistoricalFilePath> historicalfilelist = null;

public HistoricalFileList(DrawingNumberV7 dnV7, DefaultPrams dft, QMSConfigurationData qmsconfigData){

    try{

        String drawings_DOMAIN = "";//gvsvr03
        String drawings_ID = "";
        String drawings_PW = "";
        String drawings_PATH = "";//file://gvsvr03/Drawings/Release PDF/
        String drawings_PATH_HISTORICAL = "";
        List temp = new LinkedList();

        for(QMSConfiguration q2: qmsconfigData.getConfigparamlist()){

            if(q2.getProperty().equals("drawings_DOMAIN")){
                drawings_DOMAIN = q2.getValue();

            }
            if(q2.getProperty().equals("drawings_ID")){
                drawings_ID = q2.getValue();

            }
            if(q2.getProperty().equals("drawings_PW")){
                drawings_PW = q2.getValue();

            }
            if(q2.getProperty().equals("drawings_PATH")){
                drawings_PATH = q2.getValue();

            }
            if(q2.getProperty().equals("drawings_PATH_HISTORICAL")){
                drawings_PATH_HISTORICAL = q2.getValue();

            }

        }

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(drawings_DOMAIN,drawings_ID,drawings_PW);

        SmbFile smbToFile = new SmbFile(drawings_PATH_HISTORICAL + dnV7.getDrawingnumbersubdirectory() + "/", auth);

        if(smbToFile.isDirectory()){
            String dmdrawno = dnV7.getDrawingnumber();
            for(SmbFile smbfile: smbToFile.listFiles(dmdrawno + "*")){

                new AppendHistoricalWatermark(smbfile);
                temp.add(new HistoricalFilePath(dnV7, smbfile.getName()));
            }
        }

        historicalfilelist = temp;

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("HistoricalFileList: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public List<HistoricalFilePath> getHistoricalfilelist() {
    return historicalfilelist;
}


}
```

Comment: spontanously, a.) the stacktrace would be helpful and b.) the output of ```directory.exists()``` would be another good place to start

Comment: Updated to add stacktrace

Comment: Updated to add is Directory result

Comment: Update to show solution.